# workbench table data import wizard imports only 7546 rows from my CSV, which is having more than 50,000 rows

Tags: mysql

I am new to using workbench and MySQL. I have a problem and will appreciate any help on this.

I am unable to import all records from my CSV to a table in MySQL database. It downloads only 7546 records from the CSV, which is having more than 50,000 rows.

Any suggestions on how solve this issue?

Comment: THe CSV file has 45 coloumns as well.